# How to transform an object into an array from REST POST output

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an Rails 5 app.

In this app I create a user with customfields. The output I get from the client (Javascript) is a bit wrong (and I have no idea how to change that). How can I "transform" the output I get into the output I must have?

**The below is what I get**

```
"user_customfields_attributes" => {
    "1533038627616" => {
        "customfield_id" => "1", "value" => "test 1"
    }, "1533038627617" => {
        "customfield_id" => "2", "value" => "test 2"
    }
}
```

**The below is what I need**

```
"user_customfields_attributes" => [{
    "customfield_id" => 1,
    "value" => "test 1"
}, {
    "customfield_id" => 2,
    "value" => "test 2"
}]
```

Thankful for all help!

Comment: I am curious, why do you need it like that?

Comment: So that it will work with the Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_customfields, allow_destroy: true

Comment: But, the original structure should work fine with nested attributes. Are you facing any errors?

Comment: No error but it is only saving the last object/value. The one with the customfield_id of 2. Not the first one. Can it be because it is not an array? At least that is what I think.

Comment: Interesting. Can you please share your form (code) and also controller action code? May be there is a better way to solve this than to modify the params manually.